# "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Cannot read property of undefined" in Typescript async function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have been working on an API with typescript and NodeJS and ran across the following problem:
I feel like my Promises don't resolve as they should in this example here:

```js
async function functionOne() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(
                prisma.raw<Type>(
                    query
                )
            );
        });
    }
async function FunctionTwo() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(
                prisma.raw<Type>(
                    query
                )
            );
        });
    }
    const one: any = await functionOne();
    const two: any = await functionTwo();

one.property.push(two[i]);
```

Now it always returns the same Error as in the title. I'm really not sure how to go on about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the prisma library returns **promise** to i feel those line should work as expected if you just await the *prisma* result:

```
async function functionOne() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(
            await prisma.raw<Type>(
                query
            )
        );
    });
}
async function FunctionTwo() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(
            await prisma.raw<Type>(
                query
            )
        );
    });
}
const one: any = await functionOne();
const two: any = await functionTwo();
one.property.push(two[i]);
```